# Web Server/Web service written in C++ in Linux/Windows Server

Tags: linux, c++, web-services, web-server, windows-server

The requirement is to have Linux/Windows Server machine without additional installations aka Java, apache tomcat/jboss, that will be able to serve as a web server and to accept web service request (I will have to write some web service in C++ that will serve under this web server).

So, the question is if there is some C++ library that provides such a simulation of web server, since from outside it should behave the same way - to get http request and to redirect to appropriate web service.

In terms of license, its preferable to have free license for commercial distribution, but really good options (that deserve their price) will be considered as well.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! While I don't know C++ I am curious: Why can you install a C library, but not a C program (like Apache)? Also: Do you know the Apache Webserver (not tomcat)? http://httpd.apache.org/

Comment: Hi Angelo, C++ is running already on this machine. The requirement is not to have any additional installations. I'll check your link. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mawg, I'm just doing research right now. So far, I'm looking on LibMongoose Library (was recommended in another forum), but its not free for commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

There are many frameworks written in C++, one of them being:

**[Cutelyst](https://cutelyst.org)** a C++11 built with Qt, with one of the best positions on [TechEmpower Benchmarks](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/).

Even though it requires Qt 5.6+ a full CMS ([CMlyst](https://github.com/cutelyst/CMlyst)) uses around 6MB of RAM while serving around 3000 requests per seconds on a single core.

It's license it's LGPLv2.1+ meaning you can use it on commercial projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after an [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) (and HTTPS) server library usable from C or C++, you should consider [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) (LGPLv3 licensed), [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) (GPL licensed, or a commercial license), or [libhttp](https://github.com/lammertb/libhttp) (MIT license) or [libmicrohttpd](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) (LGPLv2.1 licensed).

With these libraries, you can quite easily make a web server from your application.

Of course, you do need to understand basic Web technologies (HTML5, AJAX, CSS). These libraries only add some HTTP/HTTPS service to your code.